# or boolean function as function argument

Tags: python, list, boolean, boolean-operations

Given

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [10, 1, 20, 30, 4]
```

I would like to check if any of the elements in `a` is present in `b`.

```
>>> [i in b for i in a]
Out[45]: [True, False, False, True]
```

The code above does part of the job. The next step could be a `reduce`.
However, I did not get the code below working without my own implementation of the or function.

```
def is_any_there(a, b):
    one_by_one = [i in b for i in a]

    def my_or(a,b):
        if a or b:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return reduce(my_or, one_by_one)
```

How can I avoid the rewriting of the `or` function?

Comment: you could make it a rather short lambda: `reduce(lambda x,y: x or y, one_by_one)`, but `any` is really what you want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_there_any` just reimplements the `any` function, available since Python 2.5:

```
any(x in b for x in a)
```

Further, `my_or` is already available as `operator.or_` in the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

If items are hashable then you can use [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [10, 1, 20, 30, 4]
>>> not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
True
>>> b = [10, 10, 20, 30, 40]
>>> not set(a).isdisjoint(b)
False
```